# syntax error in mysql with php using inner join

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

i have a select query with inner join i try it in phpmyadmin it work fine

but when i try it in the browser it display this error msg :

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT s.specialization_name FROM user u INNER JO' at line 1**

the query is :

```
elseif($_POST['listbyq']=="by_specialization")

   {
      $querySrting="SELECT s.specialization_name FROM user u 
                             INNER JOIN specialization s 
                                         ON u.specialization=s.specialization_id";

      $result = mysql_query($querySrting)  or die("there is an error in this query");
      $queryMSG="showing members with specs";
```

Comment: Don't use the _deprecated_ `mysql_*` extension for new code, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` (`i` stands for improved)... and above else: don't use reserved keywords

Comment: Considering you are getting a MySQL error yet your `or die()` is a custom message, are you showing us the correct code?

Comment: Just a small point but mysql_query is deprecated, you should instead use mysqli.  There is a fantastic tool to convert your existing code automatically here: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi

Comment: use **`** in table name before and after user and other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Since `user` is not a reserved word, there is most likely a foreign character that is causing the error (located near `INNER JO`).

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
$querySrting="SELECT s.specialization_name FROM user u INNER JOIN specialization s ON u.specialization=s.specialization_id";
```

Comment: i did change the table name from user to members but the system still display the msg error and i used your answer **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT s.specialization_name FROM members u INNER JOIN specialization s ON u.spe' at line 1**

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b332), and seems to work fine. One thing that sometimes works, is removing all whitespace and writing it again (there might be a non-displayable character in there that is messing the query). Another thing, you spelled it "Srting", that reads like trouble in the future.